# Vertical cell alignment in tables?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx

This problem drives me crazy right now. How can I draw a table with the following properties in Latex?

- width = \textwidth
- 1 column: horizontal alignment = left, vertical alignment = bottom
- 2 column: horizontal alignment = center, vertical alignment = bottom
- 3 column: horizontal alignment = center, vertical alignment = bottom

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|p{0.4cm}|p{3cm}|}
  \hline
  \blindtext & \begin{center}A\end{center} & \begin{center}B\end{center} \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can collect the cell contents using [`collcell`](http://ctan.org/pkg/collcell) and pass it to a `\parbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/KOMA-script
\usepackage{array,blindtext,collcell}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{array,blindtext,collcell}
\newcommand{\leftcol}[1]{\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\linewidth-6\tabcolsep-4\arrayrulewidth-4mm-3cm}{\strut #1\strut}}
\newcommand{\middlecol}[1]{\parbox[b]{4mm}{\centering\strut #1\strut}}
\newcommand{\rightcol}[1]{\parbox[b]{3cm}{\centering\strut #1\strut}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\collectcell\leftcol}l<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\middlecol}l<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\rightcol}l<{\endcollectcell}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|L|C|R|}
  \hline
  \cci\blindtext & A & B \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Each column's contents is captured and passed to a column-specific macro, detailing the required formatting.

`\cci` may not be necessary. See the [`collcell` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/collcell/collcell.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

For example (one line of your code commented, three added; line with `babel` only for my needs):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[english,polish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{}b{#1}}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|p{0.4cm}|p{3cm}|}
  \hline
%  \blindtext & \begin{center}A\end{center} & \begin{center}B\end{center} \\
\blindtext & \hfil A \hfil& \hfil B \hfil\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I could accept two answers I would also accept your solution. I have voted for the solution from Werner because it is more "general" and easier to adapt to other tables (with other alignment requirements) although your solution is short and sweet.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a rather minimal answer, similar in some ways to both of the others, but not requiring extra commands or extra `\hfil`s in the table body:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|>{\centering}b{0.4cm}|>{\centering 
    \arraybackslash}b{3cm}|}
  \hline
  \blindtext & A& B\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```